# Node Inspector is Not Pausing on the Breakpoint

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

Currently, I am using Node V 9.3.0 and While debugging the node-inspector with Chrome Dev Tool, The request is not paused on the breakpoints, Can you please help me here

Steps to reproduce

1. `killall`
2. `node node app.js`
3. `node --inspect-brk app.js`

I have below code line in the app.js

```
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);
```

And I have below code in users.js

```
router.get('/profile', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("User Profile");
});
```

Now I put the breakpoint on the line `router.get('/profile', (req, res, next) =>` { and run page the with **http://localhost:3000/users/profile** , Page loads immediately without pausing. Can you please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in pausing before serving up the page, the breakpoint may need to be on the `res.send("User Profile")` line instead of the `router.get...` line

Comment: I have tried that but I am getting error immediately not sure what is the reason

`events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:999:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1020:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1379:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1508:7)`

Comment: I've seen that kind of error when I run 2 applications at the same time with Node. I'd need to see more of your source to help any further.